# How is this method exceeding the Rubocop Account Branch Condition size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I have a simple `before_save` method used to assign an `account_id` based on whether a `user_id`, `application_id` or `contact_id` is already present in the model.

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account

  before_save :assign_account_id

  private

  def assign_account_id
    self.account_id =
      if user_id.present?
        user.account.id
      elsif application_id.present?
        application.account.id
      elsif contact_id.present?
        contact.account.id
      end
  end
end
```

The method works and, in my opinion, is about as simple as I can get it, but Rubocop insists it is slightly over the Assign Branch Condition size (ABC size), where the limit is **15** and my method's ABC is **15.33**.

According to [this article](http://redgreenrepeat.com/2017/01/20/understanding-assignment-branch-condition/), the ABC size of 15 is achieved with 8 assignments, 8 branches and 8 conditions. However, I only count 1 assignment `self.account_id =`, 1 branch (the return), and three conditions (the 3 if/elsif statements).

Am I mistaken? Where are the additional assignments, branches or conditions coming from? The calls to `present?`, traversing the model hierarchy?

**NOTE:** I'm note looking for alternative implementations, I'm interested in understanding what is causing this score.

---

For anyone interested, here's the solution I eventually went with that satisfies the ABC size.

```
self.account_id = [
  user&.account&.id,
  application&.account&.id,
  contact&.account&.id
].find(&:present?)
```

I chose it because of the vertical list conveys the cascading nature of the fields the most strongly. I felt I'd be able to return to this and still be able to grok what it's doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is the web page](http://wiki.c2.com/?AbcMetric) that the `rubocop` documentation [references in its source code](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/440c0d2c3ef75cc329d3be1e75c85854596e9255/config/default.yml#L1619-L1628), in the documentation for `Metrics/AbcSize` (as of the latest version; `0.61.0`).

To paraphrase, it says that:

> A scalar ABC size value (or "aggregate magnitude") is computed as:
>   `|ABC| = sqrt((A*A)+(B*B)+(C*C))`

Where **A** is the number of **Assignments**, **B** is the number of **Branches** and **C** is the number of **Conditions**.

- Your code has **1 Assignment** (`self.account_id =`).
- Your code has **15 Branches** (!!!) (`user_id`, `.present?`, `user`, `.account`, `.id`, `application_id`, `.present?`, `application`, `.account`, `.id`, `contact_id`, `.present?`, `contact`, `.account` and `.id`)
- Your code has **3 Conditions** (`if ... elsif ... elsif`).

Plugging this into the above formula gives:

```
ABC = sqrt(1*1 + 15*15 + 3*3)
    = sqrt(235)
    = 15.32970...
```

And that's where the (rounded) value of `15.33` is coming from.

---

I know you're not really asking for an alternative implementation, but here's one anyway:

```
def assign_account_id
  self.account_id = (user || application || contact).account.id
end
```

...And you could even consider moving those brackets into a separate method.

Comment: Regarding the alternative solution, I suspect the author might be simulating a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if the dot notation counted as a branch since later I read that function calls were branches.

Comment: @Drenmi good guess, but really this model just has a lot of possible associations and needed a cleaner denormalized way of getting at the account it was related to.